# Angular app on tablet lacking internet connection

Tags: android, angular, cordova, progressive-web-apps

**I have an existing Angular 7 application that now needs to run in fullscreen mode on an Android tablet that does not have an internet connection**.

My worst-case scenario currently is to rebuilt the app using e.g. React Native.

- Does Angular offer anything out of the box that can be used to run my app on a tablet in fullscreen mode without internet connection? Is this something that could be achieved with PWA functionality?
- Or, is there anything I can straightforwardly wrap my app in to achieve this? I am thinking of something like Electron, that just packages up the app, but for mobile? Is this something that could be achieved with Cordova?

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple with new angular cli, just use below command in your project.

ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*

refer below link to learn more: Official docs.
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

There are lots of tutorials, hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add:

Not sure if full screen is supported out of the box. A PWA is already without browsers address element when the user (you) adds it to the home screen. But if you really want to lock in the user (e.g. disable home button) you need a thing called "kiosk mode".

Good Luck!